# Is there a good reference to see the inequality of distances in measure aspect?

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

There are some distance functions that I am interested in, and I want to know the inequality between these functions and other famous distance functions on measure.
Is there any good reference for that?

Functions of my interest:

- $L^p$ distance between probability density function (especially, $p = \infty$)
- (Gromov-)Wasserstein distance

For example, I want to know many inequalities like

- $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \operatorname{Kolm}(\mu, \nu) &:=\sup _{x \in \mathbb{R}}|\mu((-\infty, x])-\nu((-\infty, x])| \\
  & \leq \operatorname{TV}(\mu, \nu) .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- $$\operatorname{Kolm}(W, Z) \leq 2 \sqrt{C \operatorname{Wass}(W, Z)}$$

Answer (score 0):

The best reference I know for these is [this](https://math.hmc.edu/su/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2019/06/ON-CHOOSING-AND-BOUNDING-PROBABILITY.pdf) paper by Gibbs and Su.